# Geodetic effect and Frame dragging

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, geodesics, gyroscopes

Two gyroscopes pointing perpendicular to each other were housed inside [Gravity Probe B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B) which performed [polar orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_orbit) around Earth to test Einstein's theory of relativity.

As the probe is orbiting around Earth, the gyroscope 1 initially point at a star is tilted slightly while moving around the Earth indicating there is a curvature of space around Earth. This tilt is attributed to [geodetic effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_effect) proving that space is curved around massive object such as Earth.

As the probe continue its polar orbit, again there is a tilt experienced by gyroscope 2 however this is called [frame dragging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging). This time round the tilt is attributed to frame dragging effect cause by a rotating Earth.

My question is how did the tilt from the gyroscope 2 explains frame dragging? I know that massive object like Earth spin on its axis, the region of space is curved as well as dragged along in the direction of rotation of Earth or am I mistaken?

I draw a sketch below to show the two gyroscopes.

[image]

Comment: The gyroscope does not have to rotate in the same direction as Earth to experience the Lense Thirring effect. The only condition I can think of is that the gyroscope spin should not be perpendicular to the equatorial plane. You get better results if the spin vector is parallel to the equatorial plane such as the 2nd gyroscope in your diagram. So the first gyroscope in your sketch does not experience the frame dragging effect. Both gyroscope positions were chosen deliberately to get the results.